# Is there any SQL or MySQL query to display all the data in a form of a sentence?

Tags: mysql

I want to display the data in a sentence like "SMITH HAS HELD THE POSITION OF CLERK IN DEPT 20 FROM 1981". How can i do this in MySQL ??
Where I'll retrieve the name , job , hiredate and dept no. from the table
And sorry I'm totally new to stack overflow

Comment: Please read this guide.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and also please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CONCAT() function to create a sentence using different values from a table column. for eg.

```
SELECT
concat(upper(name)," HAS HELD THE POSITION OF ",upper(job)," IN DEPT ",deptno," FROM ",year(hiredate)) as EmployeeInfo
FROM tbl;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4AEvyoL8c2RAaPmsu6nux/1)

you can change the query according to your requirement (as you did not provide any data we are can't provide exact query).

Comment: @DevendraYadav if this answer helps you you can press the +1 or up arrow on the left had side of the answer (`:-)`)  . If this is the best answer you can tick the tick too :-)